# Executing a command (with arguments that might contain spaces) which is stored as array

Tags: bash

While trying to adapt this example from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444949/156022)

```
mycmd=(ls)               # initial command
if [ "$want_detail" = 1 ]; then
    mycmd+=(-l)          # optional flag
fi
mycmd+=("$targetdir")    # the filename

"${mycmd[@]}"
```

I came up with

```
mycmd=(python3 /tmp/test.py)
A="a value"
B="b value"
ARGS="-a ${A} -b ${B}"
mycmd+=("$ARGS")
"${mycmd[@]}"
```

The reason that I'm not adding each flag on its own (like `mycmd+=(-l)` in the original example) is because I have 9 of them so I'm trying to avoid adding each flag and its value on a separate line (18 extra lines).

The problem is that `test.py` receives the arguments as a single string. I also suspect I'll have other issues because the values of my arguments might contain spaces (which can probably be solved with `ARGS="-a \"${A}\" -b \"${B}\""`?).

```
$ bash -x /tmp/test.sh
+ mycmd=(python3 /tmp/test.py)                          
+ A='a value'                                           
+ B='b value'                                           
+ ARGS='-a a value -b b value'                          
+ mycmd+=("$ARGS")                                      
+ python3 /tmp/test.py '-a a value -b b value'          
usage: test.py [-h] -a A -b B                           
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: -b
```

Comment: In your `ls` example, it should be `mycmd+=(-- "$targetdir")` btw, not `mycmd+=("$targetdir")`, especially if you can't guarantee that `$targetdir` won't start with `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not adding each flag on its own ...

That's the problem. You kinda defeated the whole point of using arrays here by squashing the separate arguments into one.

> I'm trying to avoid adding each flag and its value on a separate line...

Then do something like:

```
mycmd+=(-a "$A") 
# or
mycmd+=(-a "$A" -b "$B")
```